# GPG can't decrypt my data because of an invalid packet

Tags: encryption, gnupg, file-encryption

I have an encrypted data containig some of my data that I am unable to decrypt. It is archived with tar, compressed with gzip and encrypted with gnupg. Today I tried to decrypt it with gpg and it failed, even though I have the the password. It is correct (gpg doesn't complain about it). I also checked older backups of the same archive (from different hardware) and I got the same result.

`gpg --list-packets` produces the following output:

```
gpg: AES.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Invalid packet
# off=0 ctb=8c tag=3 hlen=2 plen=13
:symkey enc packet: version 4, cipher 7, aead 0, s2k 3, hash 2
    salt 3C52124CADDC256F, count 65011712 (255)
# off=15 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=6 plen=1289411052 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 1289411052
    mdc_method: 2
# off=40 ctb=ae tag=11 hlen=5 plen=1289411006
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1692001035, name="instagram-data.zip",
    raw data: 1289410982 bytes
```

Is there anything else I can try in order to decrypt my data?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Perhaps you need to build a "pipeline" with 2 pipes and the order is incorrect?

Comment: I don't see why a pipeline would be necessary. I am simply trying to decrypt it, not to extract it.

Comment: (1) the PGP redundancy check is only 16 bits, so lack of detection that a pw is wrong doesn't really prove it is right; however, production of an apparently valid lit-data packet does (2) I notice the tag19 packet that should follow tag18 is missing; this _may_ mean the problem is in that packet OR the MDC check and if so **`--ignore-mdc-error` _may_ help** -- but if so check resulting output carefully (3) If you really named a tar-gz file `.zip` that's highly misleading

Comment: I made a mistake. It was not archived with tar and gzip and named .zip. It was archived with 7zip and named .zip.

Answer (score 0):

Gnupg complained about the error and some data must have been lost, but after decrypting the file, I got a (largely?) intact archive and I recovered a large fraction of the data. It was my mistake to assume that gpg had no output after seeing the "decryption failed" error message. Also, thanks a lot to Dave Thompson! Had it not been for his comment, it wouldn't have crossed my mind that I had misnamed the file (indicating the wrong program use for extracting it).

Comment: Welcome to the community (again). Umm, please edit your answer to include the information in the comment above that you outputted a wrong file ending, which doesn't matter much in Linux and can be checked with the `file` command